# Reset CSS for Embedded scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I'm working on a JS app that webmasters embed on their sites. It adds a fixed element to their site with a certain functionality, as well as a `<style>` tag with css in the `head` of the page in order to style it. It's pretty similar to [wibiya](http://wibiya.conduit.com/) in that aspect.

I have trouble finding correct css rules for this requirements:

- My styles won't overload styles of elements in the page
- The page style won't overload my styles
- My style should still have the upper hand if the page declares something `important!`

I'm inserting the CSS on DOM ready but I have no guarantees that that my style is the last one inserted into the page.

I'm not editing elements inside the page. I have a container and all my elements are within that container.

I tried Meyer's CSS Reset specifically for the container and all objects within, but the site rules still override my rules.

How would I approach this?

Comment: You should show a few examples. In general using "body" at the beginning of a CSS declaration will override previous declarations. Avoid !important where ever you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have a stylesheet to style your "module"? here's some tips:

1. override styles by loading your CSS last. usually, so that i avoid jQuery UI from being overridden with my styles, I load it's CSS last for safety.
2. The order of styles' importance (as far as i remember) are in this order:

   1. browser styles
   2. stylesheet styles
   3. inline styles
   4. `!important` styles
   5. user-defined/user-script styles (custom browser fonts and colors).

   That's why libraries like jQuery apply inline styles (as opposed to addClass methods) because it always overrides the stylesheet styles, no matter the specificity. but you can override them using `!important`
3. [Know specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). this is also the reason why jQuery UI stylesheets have very long/specific style declarations. the more specific it is, the harder it is to override. to demonstrate, the following will always be green even if a definition of red comes after it:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/FgshA/):

```
<span class="red">I'm supposed to be red</span>​

span.red{color:green}
.red{color:red}
```

​

Comment: Thank you both - I didn't figure the importance order correctly. The articles helped refresh my memory

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific than their rules. **[Here's an article on the subject!](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**

For instance, if their rule is as follows:

```
.button { background: red; }
```

If you are more specific:

```
a.button {}
body .button {}
```

Your rules will win.

---

If the embedded page uses !important rules, you'll need to use more specific !important rules. But try not to start a rule war between you and the script. The results are usually unexpected!

Comment: Can specificity win over `important!`

Comment: Like I said, specificity will win in case your rule is also `!important`, meaning if they have an important rule, you must override with an important rule of yourself, **with a greater specificity value**.

Comment: @Diodeus: When not, if I may ask?

Comment: You can make your declaration MORE specific, but if there is no way to make it more specific you have to resort to !important.

Comment: @Diodeus: Sure there is. `.red { background: red !important; }` will lose to `span.red { background: green !important; }`.

Comment: True, but the issue is you can only go up the tree so far, then you run out.