# Highlighting the clicked row of a striped HTML table

Tags: javascript, css

[Here's an example of my problem on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xu2AH/5/)

I have a table with striped rows imposed by using `tr:nth-child(odd)` in the CSS, as is done in Twitter Bootstrap for the `table-striped` class. I want to highlight the most recent clicked row of that table. I do that with the following Javascript:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function(event) {
    $clicked_tr = $(this);
    $clicked_tr.parent().children().each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight')
    });
    $clicked_tr.addClass('highlight');
});
```

That code works fine in a table without striped rows. But with striped rows, the background color of the `highlight` class won't override the background color of the `table-striped` class. Why is that? And how can I make it work?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xu2AH/9/

.table-striped class

```
.table-striped tbody tr.highlight td { background-color: red; }
```

... and cleaner jQuery:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});​
```

**Update:** `.live()` has since been deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});​
```

**Fixed:** http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xu2AH/127/

Comment: How to do this on a dynamically loaded table, binding events with JavaScript may not be a right solution then?

Answer (score 19):

[Increase the specificity](http://jsfiddle.net/xu2AH/7/) of the `.highlight`

Learn more "CSS specificity" by reading [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and checking out the demo in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927873/575527)

```
//your normal green has "023"
//.table-striped  010
//tbody           001
//tr              001
//:nth-child(odd) 010 
//td              001 = 023
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: green;
}

// your highlight only has "010"
//thus it can't take precedence over the applied style
.highlight{
    background-color: red
}

//a more specific highlight =  "033" will take precedence now
//.table-striped  010
//tbody           001       
//tr              001       everything is about the same except
//.highlight      010   <-- an added class can boost specificity
//:nth-child(odd) 010 
//td              001 = 033
.table-striped tbody tr.highlight:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is much easier, just use de Bootstrap css classes (like .info .warning .error or .success) to switch between the selected row and not selected. They have all the states for the row.

I used this, based on @iambriansreed answer:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('info').siblings().removeClass('info');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the Bootstrap `.table-striped` CSS class to this:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd),
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Remove all the td styling you do not want. Then it works.

When you click the row this style should also be applied:

```
.selected { background-color:#2f96b4 !important; }
```

It will not work without the `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function(event) {
    $clicked_tr = $(this);
    $('#mytable tbody tr').removeClass("highlight");
    $clicked_tr.addClass('highlight');
});​
```