# Trying to highlight a row in a table when user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replicate your solution above from the JS Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xu2AH/9/) but can't load it.
What am I missing?

I am trying to implement the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952320/highlighting-the-clicked-row-of-a-striped-html-table).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

.table-striped  tr.highlight td { 
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

$('#mytable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="mytable" class="table-striped">
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This click even't isn't being triggered because the DOM isn't created, therefor jQuery can't find an element to bind the click event. You should be loading your javascript at the end of the body or wrap your javascript in a window onload function. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6n5JB/)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

.table-striped  tr.highlight td { 
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<table id="mytable" class="table-striped">
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

$('#mytable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it by putting the <script> after the table. Is it possible to change the code so that multiple rows can be selected?

Comment: Yea just remove `.siblings().removeClass('highlight')` and the row will stay highlighted. To check if an element already has a class you can use `$(this).hassClass("highlight")`, so if the row is clicked again you can remove the highlight class.

Comment: Great that worked, I'm still trying to learn it all. So am I write in saying `$('#leaderboard').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    $(this).hasClass('highlight');`

Comment: Perfect, that's the job. What's the best tutorial site to learn all of this on? 
I want to be able to save the clicked rows after the page refreshes with new data

Answer (score 2):

Your are targetting:

```
tbody tr
```

But tbody doesnt exist in your html, so remove tbody from the jQuery and it should work.

Like this:

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: explains why it's working in some browsers, as some browsers (due to HTML engine error correction) insert the `tbody` automatically.

Comment: This still won't work because the javascript is loaded BEFORE the DOM is created.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how fast jQuery is loaded, the event handler is bound and the DOM is ready. To make sure, wrap the event in `$(function(){/*event handler*/});`. The difference is usually triggered when using `F5` vs `CTRL+F5`

Comment: @TimVermaelen do you got any idea why [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158931/trying-to-highlight-a-row-in-a-table-when-user-clicks/23158998#23158998) is working because it still uses the 'tbody tr' selector.

Comment: yes, it's called cache, which is faster than fetching a script + see my first comment to answer your question

Comment: Could just wrap the entire listener in a document.ready function and its bulletproof :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `tbody` in you dom. 
Use

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Just take off the `tbody` from click event.